# Android -> Cambiar Switch con Intents a For con Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, bucle-for

Tengo un Switch con muchos cases y mismo código y quiero pasarlo a un for para reducir código pero me da error de programación. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("exp", Operaciones[0][1]);
                        i.putExtra("sab", Operaciones[0][2]);
                        i.putExtra("dificultad", Operaciones[0][3]);
                        i.putExtra("op", Operaciones[0][4]);
                        i.putExtra("stage", 0);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
                        i2.putExtra("exp", Operaciones[1][1]);
                        i2.putExtra("sab", Operaciones[1][2]);
                        i2.putExtra("dificultad", Operaciones[1][3]);
                        i2.putExtra("op", Operaciones[1][4]);
                        i2.putExtra("stage", 0);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;

    .......
}
```

Quiero transformarlo en un for como este:
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        for(position=0; position<6; position++){
            Intent i[position] = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class); //esta linea da error
            i[position].putExtra("exp", Operaciones[0][1]);
            i[position].putExtra("sab", Operaciones[0][2]);
            i[position].putExtra("dificultad", Operaciones[0][3]);
            i[position].putExtra("op", Operaciones[0][4]);
            i[position].putExtra("stage", 0);
            startActivity(i[position]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es una función y objetos.

Una sentencia `switch` te funciona como condicionales `if/else`. Por lo que no debes ponerlo en un ciclo. Simplemente crea una funcion y pasale un objeto personalizado. No debes crear un arreglo de dos dimensiones para almacenar una gran cantidad de datos, ya que no es muy mantenible. Si lo que quieres es almacenar muchos datos del mismo tipo crea un objeto.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Operaciones {

    private String exp;
    private String sab;
    private String dificultad;
    private String op;
    private String stage;

    public Operaciones(String exp, String sab, String dificultad, String op, String stage){
        this.exp = exp;
        this.sab = sab;
        this.dificultad = dificultad;
        this.op = op;
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Operaciones(){}

    public String getExp() {
        return this.exp;
    }
    public void setExp(String exp) {
        this.exp = exp;
    }
    public String getSab() {
        return this.sab;
    }
    public void setSab(String sab) {
        this.sab = sab;
    }
    public void setDificultad(String dificultad){
        this.dificultad = dificultad;
    }
    public String getDificultad(){
        return this.dificultad;
    }

    public String getOp(){
        return this.op;
    }
    public void setOp(String op){
        this.op = op;
    }
    public String getStage(){
        return this.stage;
    }
    public void setStage(String stage){
        this.stage = stage;
    }
}
```

Creas la funcion que inicia la actividad y le pasas el objeto como parametro.

```
private void IniciarActividad(Operaciones operaciones){
      Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
      i.putExtra("exp", operaciones.getExp());
      i.putExtra("sab", operaciones.getSab());
      i.putExtra("dificultad", operaciones.getDificultad());
      i.putExtra("op", operaciones.getOp());
      i.putExtra("stage", operaciones.getStage());
      startActivity(i);
}
```

En tu sentencia de switch:

```
. . .
. . .
switch(position){

   case 0:
      IniciarActividad(new Operaciones(/*aqui pasas los parametros correspondientes*/)); 
   case 1:
      IniciarActividad(new Operaciones(/*aqui pasas los parametros correspondientes*/));

. . . 
. . .
```

Nota: Lo ideal seria que tengas los datos que estan en tu arreglo bidimensional como un `ArrayList<Operaciones>` para que no tengas que crear un nuevo objeto por cada caso solo tendrias que llamar el item de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
private ArrayList<Operaciones> Items = new ArrayList<Operaciones>();
```

Lo llenas con tus datos, ejemplo:

```
Items.add(new Operaciones(/* pasas los parametros */));
Items.add(new Operaciones(/* pasas los parametros */));
Items.add(new Operaciones(/* pasas los parametros */));
Items.add(new Operaciones(/* pasas los parametros */));
Items.add(new Operaciones(/* pasas los parametros */));
etc...
```

en este punto ya no hace falta crear el `switch` ya que cada item es diferente y lo llamarias asi:

```
. . .
. . .
IniciarActividad(Items[position]);
. . . 
. . .
```

Buena suerte.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes error porque no se debe definir un Intent de esta forma:

```
  Intent i[position] = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
```

debería ser simplemente:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
```

Por lo tanto cambia tu código a esta forma, así puedes crear varios `intents`:

```
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Intent i;

        for(position=0; position<6; position++){
            i = new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class); 
            i.putExtra("exp", Operaciones[0][1]);
            i.putExtra("sab", Operaciones[0][2]);
            i.putExtra("dificultad", Operaciones[0][3]);
            i.putExtra("op", Operaciones[0][4]);
            i.putExtra("stage", 0);
            startActivity(i);
        }

}
```

No necesitas crear un array de `intents`, ya que la `Activity` que inicia el `intent` y la `Activity` que se abrirá son siempre la misma en este caso, lo único que varia son los datos que envias.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que con esta linea:

```
Intent i[position]=new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
```

lo que quieres sería simular el crear i1, i2, i3...in pero no funciona de esa manera no puedes concatenar en el nombre de las variables, la solución para lo que quieres hacer sería crear un array de intents no se si se pueda hacer y no tengo como probarlo pero en caso de que se pudiera sería algo así

```
Intent i[]=new Intent[6];
```

y ahora si podría funcionar tu código donde utilizas el for solo así:

```
i[position]=new Intent(Inicio.this, OpActivity.class);
```